# jquery mobile getting the html head duplicated and pop up not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am getting the html "head" part duplicated in the script and also the pop up does not open when it is clicked.It only changes color when I click it but nothing shows up.I would like to know what is wrong with the code. I get this at the address bar "#&ui-state=dialog". Here is the address of the website https://barexpress.club/mobile_detect_device/contact_us

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website Contact Us</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="popup" id="settings_popup_beer_quantity" data-position="right">     
    <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b" style="min-width:210px;">
               <li data-role="list-divider">Settings</li>
               <li data-icon="false"><?php echo anchor('login/logout/','Logout',       array('title'=>"Logout",  "rel" =>"external"));?></li>
               <li data-icon="false"><?php echo anchor('customer_settings/','Settings',array('title'=>"Settings","rel" =>"external"));?></li>
               </ul>
               </div>         
<div style="float:left;">
                        <img class="small_logo" border="0" src="<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/small_logo.png"  alt="cup Bar Express" />
                        </div>
<div data-role="header" style="width:100px;float:right;" data-position="right"> 
    <div class="settings_button_quantity" data-role="navbar">   
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#settings_popup_beer_quantity" data-rel="popup"  data-transition="pop" class="settings_popup_link_quantity ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-bars">Settings</a></li>          
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>                                                       
   <div role="main" class="ui-content" >
        <div class="background_image">      
    <div class="ui-grid-solo" id="title">QUANTITY</div> 
        <ul  data-role="listview" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true">
<?php 


?>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 

<style type="text/css">  
.ui-listview>li h1, .ui-listview>li h2, .ui-listview>li h3, .ui-listview>li h4, .ui-listview>li h5, .ui-listview>li h6{
                                                                                                                       padding-top: 0px;
                                                                                                                       height     : 37px;
                                                                                                                       margin-top : 0px;
                                                                                                                       font-family:'RNS Camelia';
                                                                                                                       text-shadow: none;
                                                                                                                       color      : black !important;
                                                                                                                       font-weight: 700;
                                                                                                                       font-size  : 33px;   
                                                                                                                       }

li h1 .display_beer_count{
                          color:white;
                         } 

.ui-listview>.ui-li-static, .ui-listview>.ui-li-divider, .ui-listview>li>a.ui-btn{                                                                         
                                                                                   padding-right:18px;
                                                                                   padding-left :18px;
                                                                                   text-align   :center;
                                                                                   background   :transparent !important;
                                                                                  }
button.ui-btn.beer_quantity_button{
                                   border    :none        !important;
                                   color     : black      !important;
                                   background: #D6DE23    !important;
                                  }

.ui-listview>li h1.add_beer_to_cart_letters {
                                              margin-bottom: 0px; 
                                              color        :white !important;
                                             }                                                                                                                           
button.add_beer_to_cart {
                          background: transparent !important;   
                        }

@font-face {
            font-family:'RNS Camelia';
            font-style : normal;
            font-weight: 900;
            src        : local('RNS Camelia'), url(<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>fonts/RNS_Camelia.otf);
           }

@font-face{
            font-family:'Simply City Light';
            font-style : normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src        : local('Simply City Light'), url(<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>fonts/siml023.ttf);
           }

.settings_button_quantity{
                          width     :100px; 
                          height    :22px; 
                          float     :right;
                         }

a .settings_popup_link_quantity{
                               height:22px;
                               }


.ui-content .ui-listview-inset, .ui-panel-inner>.ui-listview-inset{
                                                                    margin:0;
                                                                   }

#title{ 
       text-shadow  : none!important;
       margin-bottom: 11px;
       width        : 100%;
       font-size    : 52px                !important;
       font-family  :'RNS Camelia'        !important;            
       color        : #D6DE23             !important;   
       padding-left : 5%;
      }

.background_image{
                  width         :100%  !important;
                  padding-bottom:160px !important;
                  margin-left   :auto  !important;
                  margin-right  :auto  !important;
                  display       :block;             
                  background    :url(<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/beer_cup.png) no-repeat;               
                  z-index       :-21;
                 }

.ui-page{
         background-image :url('<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/background.png') !important;
         width            :100%;
         background-size  :100% 100%;
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         } 

.small_logo{
            padding-top: 4px;
            width      : 138px;
            height     : 52px;
           } 

#settings_popup_beer_quantity li a,#settings_popup_beer_quantity,.ui-navbar li:last-child .ui-btn {
                                                                                                   color      :black              !important;
                                                                                                   font-family:'Simply City Light'!important;
                                                                                                   }  
#settings_popup_beer_quantity .ui-li-divider{
                                             background:black!important;
                                             }           
    </style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? The site is completely broken! Look at the generated HTML: you have two html pages in one! see the source code: `...</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>...`

Comment: It is weird because that is the code I am uploading to my server.

Comment: What do you mean with "uploaded to the server"? Have you checked whether the script on the server is really the same as posted above? Lookes like you `vi`ed into it and pasted in the code two times.

Comment: I checked the script in the localhost and has the same duplicate of the head. There is no duplicate in the script. The duplicate appears when the files are on the server. I think it has to do something with jquery mobile.

Comment: No, it must be a different bug on your _server_. jQuery mobile is a _Javascript_, but the duplicate page get's generated by the server! Javascript cannot write the HTML source code that comes from the server! - it could just manipulate the DOM and for this it needs to be executed, but you can see the duplicate pages also, when you just `wget https://barexpress.club/mobile_detect_device/contact_us` or otherwise load the HTML without executing the JS - there has to be something wrong on your server side (PHP)!

Comment: You are right. I am using codeigniter and two views were being outputted by the server in the same function . Thanks !